# Highstock data grouping navigator issue

Tags: highcharts

I am experiencing an undesired behavior with the data grouping feature of Highstock. I'm not sure whether it's a bug or am I missing something.

This is the JSON object for the chart configuration:

```
{"chart":{"renderTo":"container","alignTicks":false,"type":"column"},"plotOptions":{"column":{"dataGrouping":{"forced":true,"smoothed":true,"units":[["day",[1]],["week",[1]],["month",[1]]]}}},"rangeSelector":{"selected":5},"series":[{"data":[[1349995778160,111.11],[1357672339000,111.11],[1359581186470,222.22],[1359581222750,222.22]],"name":"Total Cost","type":"column"}],"xAxis":{"maxPadding":0.05,"minPadding":0.05,"ordinal":false}}
```

The timestamps in data array point to the following datetimes (GMT): 2012-10-11 22:49:38.160, 2013-01-08 19:12:19, 2013-01-30 21:26:26.470, 2013-01-30 21:27:02.750, respectively.

**The issue**: when rendered, the navigator is set to "All", which displays the whole data interval bound by 2012-10-11 and 2013-01-30, with the specified 5% padding at both ends. As well, data is grouped correctly - per month - as specified in data grouping units configuration. So far, so good. But when I narrow the navigator range using (at least one of) the cursors, data that should not be displayed anymore - because it gets out of the range - is still displayed at the end(s) that has(ve) been narrowed, with wrong timestamp information.

Why are the points outside the navigator range still grouped at the ends of the selected interval?

Also the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/andreinic/fLmza/. All you have to try is "play" with the navigator cursors and see what happens with the leftmost and rightmost data.

Comment: It's probably the same bug as this one: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1486

Comment: Ok, thanks. But is there any answer on that?

Comment: I suggest to stay on track with gitHub thread and when fix will be published then you can use master version.